# How to read data into TensorFlow batches from example queue?

Tags: python, numpy, classification, tensorflow

How do I get TensorFlow example queues into proper batches for training?

I've got some images and labels:

```
IMG_6642.JPG 1
IMG_6643.JPG 2
```

(feel free to suggest another label format; I think I may need another dense to sparse step...)

I've read through quite a few tutorials but don't quite have it all together yet.
Here's what I have, with comments indicating the steps required from TensorFlow's [Reading Data](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#reading-from-files) page.

1. The list of filenames
   (optional steps removed for the sake of simplicity)
2. Filename queue
3. A Reader for the file format
4. A decoder for a record read by the reader
5. Example queue

And after the example queue I need to get this queue into batches for training; that's where I'm stuck...

**1. List of filenames**

`files = tf.train.match_filenames_once('*.JPG')`

**4. Filename queue**

`filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(files, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True, seed=None, shared_name=None, name=None)`

**5. A reader**

`reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)`

**6. A decoder**

`record_defaults = [[""], [1]]
col1, col2 = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)`

(I don't think I need this step below because I already have my label in a tensor but I include it anyways)

`features = tf.pack([col2])`

The documentation page has an example to run one image, not get the images and labels into batches:

`for i in range(1200):
    # Retrieve a single instance:
    example, label = sess.run([features, col5])`

And then below it has a batching section:

```
def read_my_file_format(filename_queue):
  reader = tf.SomeReader()
  key, record_string = reader.read(filename_queue)
  example, label = tf.some_decoder(record_string)
  processed_example = some_processing(example)
  return processed_example, label

def input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size, num_epochs=None):
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
  filenames, num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)
  example, label = read_my_file_format(filename_queue)
  # min_after_dequeue defines how big a buffer we will randomly sample
  #   from -- bigger means better shuffling but slower start up and more
  #   memory used.
  # capacity must be larger than min_after_dequeue and the amount larger
  #   determines the maximum we will prefetch.  Recommendation:
  #   min_after_dequeue + (num_threads + a small safety margin) *              batch_size
  min_after_dequeue = 10000
  capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
  example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
  [example, label], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
  min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
  return example_batch, label_batch
```

My question is: **how do I use the above example code with the code I have above?**  I need *batches* to work with, and most of the tutorials come with mnist batches already.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)

  # Training cycle
for epoch in range(training_epochs):
    total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)
    # Loop over all batches
    for i in range(total_batch):
        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I am also looking for an explanation of it. I have the impression that the mnist example process the output to create a "cost" making the code too specific. I can not find any other example to help me sort it out.

Answer (score 15):

If you wish to make this input pipeline work, you will need add an asynchronous queue'ing mechanism that generate batches of examples. This is performed by creating a `tf.RandomShuffleQueue` or a `tf.FIFOQueue` and inserting JPEG images that have been read, decoded and preprocessed.

You can use handy constructs that will generate the Queues and the corresponding threads for running the queues via `tf.train.shuffle_batch_join` or `tf.train.batch_join`. Here is a simplified example of what this would like. Note that this code is untested:

```
# Let's assume there is a Queue that maintains a list of all filenames
# called 'filename_queue'
_, file_buffer = reader.read(filename_queue)

# Decode the JPEG images
images = []
image = decode_jpeg(file_buffer)

# Generate batches of images of this size.
batch_size = 32

# Depends on the number of files and the training speed.
min_queue_examples = batch_size * 100
images_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch_join(
  image,
  batch_size=batch_size,
  capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * batch_size,
  min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)

# Run your network on this batch of images.
predictions = my_inference(images_batch)
```

Depending on how you need to scale up your job, you might need to run multiple independent threads that read/decode/preprocess images and dump them in your example queue. A complete example of such a pipeline is provided in the Inception/ImageNet model. Take a look at `batch_inputs`:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/image_processing.py#L407

Finally, if you are working with >O(1000) JPEG images, keep in mind that it is extremely inefficient to individually ready 1000's of small files. This will slow down your training  quite a bit.

A more robust and faster solution to convert a dataset of images to a sharded `TFRecord` of `Example` protos. Here is a fully worked [script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/README.md#getting-started) for converting the ImageNet data set to such a format. And here is a set of [instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/README.md#how-to-construct-a-new-dataset-for-retraining) for running a generic version of this preprocessing script on an arbitrary directory containing JPEG images.