# ResourceExhaustedError in Python when allocating tensor

Tags: python, out-of-memory

This problem exists when I try to run the train.py from keras-mplecules-master (    https://github.com/maxhodak/keras-molecules
). It appears to be my graphic cards don't have enough memory. Is there any way to solve this? Thank You.
My graphic card is a GTX970 with 4GB ram. Thanks.

Error message :

```
    ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[600,120,1503]
```

I have read a very similar problem 
    [Tensorflow Deep MNIST: Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[10000,32,28,28]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076388/tensorflow-deep-mnist-resource-exhausted-oom-when-allocating-tensor-with-shape)
but I still don't know how should I change my code.
I am new to ubuntu, so please be specific if possible. Thank You.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and please provide the Python version you are using.

Answer (score 2):

The problem have been solve.
This is a problem related to the RAM usage.
It can be solved by limiting the batch_size thus less RAM is used at the same time and the problem will be solved.