# Tensorflow OOM on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, out-of-memory, gpu, vram

i'm training some Music Data on a LSTM-RNN in Tensorflow and encountered some Problem with GPU-Memory-Allocation which i don't understand: I encounter an OOM when there actually seems to be just about enough VRAM still available. 
Some background: 
I'm working on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, using a GTX1060 6GB, Intel Xeon E3-1231V3 and 8GB RAM. 
So now first the part of the error-message which i can understand, in the and i will add the whole error message in the end again for anyone who might ask for it to help:

> I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 8 Chunks of
>   size 256 totalling 2.0KiB I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 1 Chunks of size
>   1280 totalling 1.2KiB I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 5 Chunks of size
>   44288 totalling 216.2KiB I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 5 Chunks of size
>   56064 totalling 273.8KiB I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 4 Chunks of size
>   154350080 totalling 588.80MiB I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 3 Chunks of size
>   813400064 totalling 2.27GiB I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 1 Chunks of size
>   1612612352 totalling 1.50GiB I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:700] Sum Total of
>   in-use chunks: 4.35GiB I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:702] Stats:
>
> Limit:        5484118016
>
> InUse:        4670717952
>
> MaxInUse:     5484118016
>
> NumAllocs:    29
>
> MaxAllocSize: 1612612352
>
> W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:274]
>   *********************___________*__***************************************************xxxxxxxxxxxxxx W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Ran out of
>   memory trying to allocate 775.72MiB.  See logs for memory state. W
>   tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Resource exhausted: OOM
>   when allocating tensor with shape[14525,14000]

So i can read that there is a maximum of 5484118016 bytes to be allocated, 
4670717952 bytes are allready in use, and another 777.72MB = 775720000 bytes are to be allocated. 5484118016 bytes - 4670717952 bytes - 775720000 bytes = 37680064 bytes according to my calculator. 
So there should still be 37MB of free VRAM after allocating the space for the new Tensor he wants to push in there. This seems also to be quite legit to me, as Tensorflow would probably (i guess?) not try to allocate more VRAM than there is still available and just put the rest of the data on hold in RAM or something.

Now i guess there is just some big error in my thinking, but i would be quite gratefull if someone could explain to me, what this error is. The obvious solving-strategy to my problem is to just make my batches a bit smaller, having them each at around 1.5GB probably just is too big. Still i would love to know what the actual problem is there.

edit: I found something telling me to try:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allocator_type = 'BFC'
with tf.Session(config = config) as s:
```

which still does not work, but as the tensorflow documentation lacks any explanation of what

```
 gpu_options.allocator_type = 'BFC'
```

would be, i would love to ask you guys.

Adding the rest of the error message for anyone interested:

Sorry for the long copy/paste, but maybe someone would need/want to see it,

Thank you so much in advance, 
Leon

```
(gputensorflow) leon@ljksUbuntu:~/Tensorflow$ python Netzwerk_v0.5.1_gamma.py 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:910] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7335
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 5.93GiB
Free memory: 5.40GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (256):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (512):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (1024):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (2048):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (4096):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (8192):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (16384):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (32768):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (65536):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (131072):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (262144):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (524288):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (1048576):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (2097152):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (4194304):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (8388608):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (16777216):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (33554432):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (67108864):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (134217728):     Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 0 147.20MiB allocated for chunks. 147.20MiB client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (268435456):     Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 0 628.52MiB allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:660] Bin for 775.72MiB was 256.00MiB, Chunk State: 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:666]   Size: 628.52MiB | Requested Size: 0B | in_use: 0, prev:   Size: 147.20MiB | Requested Size: 147.20MiB | in_use: 1, next:   Size: 54.8KiB | Requested Size: 54.7KiB | in_use: 1
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x10208000000 of size 1280
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x10208000500 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x10208000600 of size 56064
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1020800e100 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1020800e200 of size 44288
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x10208018f00 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x10208019000 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x10208019100 of size 813400064
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x102387d1100 of size 56064
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x102387dec00 of size 154350080
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x10241b11e00 of size 44288
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x10241b1cb00 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x10241b1cc00 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x10241b1cd00 of size 154350080
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x102722d4d00 of size 56064
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1027b615a00 of size 44288
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1027b620700 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1027b620800 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x1027b620900 of size 813400064
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x102abdd8900 of size 813400064
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x102dc590900 of size 56064
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x102dc59e400 of size 56064
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x102dc5abf00 of size 154350080
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x102e58df100 of size 154350080
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x102eec12300 of size 44288
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x102eec1d000 of size 44288
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x102eec27d00 of size 1612612352
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:687] Free at 0x1024ae4ff00 of size 659049984
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:687] Free at 0x102722e2800 of size 154350080
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:693]      Summary of in-use Chunks by size: 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 8 Chunks of size 256 totalling 2.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 1 Chunks of size 1280 totalling 1.2KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 5 Chunks of size 44288 totalling 216.2KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 5 Chunks of size 56064 totalling 273.8KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 4 Chunks of size 154350080 totalling 588.80MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 3 Chunks of size 813400064 totalling 2.27GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 1 Chunks of size 1612612352 totalling 1.50GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:700] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 4.35GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:702] Stats: 
Limit:                  5484118016
InUse:                  4670717952
MaxInUse:               5484118016
NumAllocs:                      29
MaxAllocSize:           1612612352

W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:274] *********************___________*__***************************************************xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Ran out of memory trying to allocate 775.72MiB.  See logs for memory state.
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[14525,14000]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1022, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1004, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[14525,14000]
     [[Node: rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights/Initializer/random_uniform = Add[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/mul, rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/min)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Netzwerk_v0.5.1_gamma.py", line 171, in <module>
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[14525,14000]
     [[Node: rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights/Initializer/random_uniform = Add[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/mul, rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/min)]]

Caused by op 'rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights/Initializer/random_uniform', defined at:
  File "Netzwerk_v0.5.1_gamma.py", line 94, in <module>
    initial_state=initial_state, time_major=False)       # time_major = FALSE currently
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 545, in dynamic_rnn
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 712, in _dynamic_rnn_loop
    swap_memory=swap_memory)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2626, in while_loop
    result = context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2459, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2409, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 697, in _time_step
    (output, new_state) = call_cell()
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 683, in <lambda>
    call_cell = lambda: cell(input_t, state)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py", line 179, in __call__
    concat = _linear([inputs, h], 4 * self._num_units, True, scope=scope)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py", line 747, in _linear
    "weights", [total_arg_size, output_size], dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 988, in get_variable
    custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 890, in get_variable
    custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 348, in get_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 333, in _true_getter
    caching_device=caching_device, validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 684, in _get_single_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 226, in __init__
    expected_shape=expected_shape)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 303, in _init_from_args
    initial_value(), name="initial_value", dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 673, in <lambda>
    shape.as_list(), dtype=dtype, partition_info=partition_info)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py", line 360, in __call__
    dtype, seed=self.seed)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py", line 246, in random_uniform
    return math_ops.add(rnd * (maxval - minval), minval, name=name)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 73, in add
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Add", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2395, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/leon/anaconda3/envs/gputensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1264, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[14525,14000]
     [[Node: rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights/Initializer/random_uniform = Add[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/mul, rnn/basic_lstm_cell/weights/Initializer/random_uniform/min)]]
```

Comment: I have encountered this problem recently, and face resource exhaust problem in the middle of training. And I followed this https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4735, and tackled this problem by decreasing the validation batch size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to take a look at this

> Be careful not to run the evaluation and training binary on the same
>   GPU or else you might run out of memory. Consider running the
>   evaluation on a separate GPU if available or suspending the training
>   binary while running the evaluation on the same GPU.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn

Comment: link is dead...

Answer (score 9):

I resolve this issue by reducing `batch_size=52`
Only to reduce memory use is to reduce batch_size.

> Batch_size depends on your gpu graphics card, size of VRAM, Cache memory etc.

Please prefer this [Another Stack Overflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076388/tensorflow-deep-mnist-resource-exhausted-oom-when-allocating-tensor-with-shape)

Answer (score 4):

Had same OOM problem running model permutations one after another. It seems after completing one model, then defining and running a new model, that GPU memory is NOT completely cleared of previous model(s), and something is building up in memory and causing eventual OOM error.

Answer from g-eoj to another problem:

```
keras.backend.clear_session()
```

should clear the previous model. From https://keras.io/backend/
Destroys the current TF graph and creates a new one. Useful to avoid clutter from old models / layers.
After running and saving one model, clear the session, then run next model.

Comment: Any other ideas without using keras?
I've tried numba but it's too hard to install with pip.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem. I shut down all the anaconda prompt windows and cleared all the python tasks. Reopened an Anaconda prompt window and executed the train.py file. It worked for me the next time. The Anaconda and Python terminals were taking up the memory which doesn't leave space for the training process.

Also, try to reduce the batch size of the training process if the above approach doesn't work.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Coming here as reducing the batch size problem didn't solve in my case. If you are having this problem during inference, the following might help:

```
with tf.device("cpu:0"):
  prediction = model.predict(...)
```

The difference between CPU and GPU inference time is not that high, and we'll have way more memory available using CPU.

Answer (score 0):

When encountering OOM on GPU I believe changing `batch size` is the right option to try at first.

> For different GPU you may need different batch size based on the GPU
>   memory you have.

Recently I faced the similar type of problem, tweaked a lot to do the different type of experiment.

Here is the link to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007984/training-broke-with-resourceexausted-error) (also some tricks are included).

However, while reducing the size of the batch you may find that your training gets slower. So if you have multiple GPU you may use them. To check about your GPU you can write on the terminal,

```
nvidia-smi
```

It will show you necessary information about your gpu rack.

Comment: For some reason, as soon as the model starts training, all of my gpu is allocated. I even tried with batch size 1.

Comment: At first do, `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='x'` on the terminal. this x is the GPU number that you want to use.

Comment: Nvidia-smi doensn't seems reachable from docker. (even with nvidia runtime)

Answer (score 0):

I have recently had a very similar error and it was due to accidentally having a training process running in the background while trying to train in a different process. Stopping one fixed the error immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Check the system usage with Ctrl+ Shift + Esc. You are running out of memory. End Tasks for unwanted tasks. It worked for me.

Comment: Had the issue on an ARM64 device used as an ssh server.
||
 1. Opened **htop**
 2. killed microK8s service.... ||

Inferences were running back to normal.

What is weird is that can occur even if there are some ressources left.
htop was more useful than jtop.
By the way if the system freeze, it's good to increase swap (jtop has a gui built in command)

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason was really stupid. I wanted to check the architecture of NN, so I had loaded tensorflow in a terminal. Even if tensorflow was loaded and not used, it was still allocating resources. I closed the terminal and the OOM disappeared